# How can I force Guest Checkout in Woocommerce using PayPal Express?

Tags: wordpress, express, paypal, woocommerce

I'm trying to launch an online store using Wordpress, WooCommerce and the "Paypal for Woocommerce" Plugin.

On Paypal, Guest Checkout is only available on mobile, but it's not an option on desktop. I read somewhere that you need to add this lines to your SetExpressCheckout API Call but I don't know where to put them:

```
SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole
LANDINGPAGE=Billing
```

Can anyone using this plugin help me? Thank you.

Comment: You have to set up your paypal `notification url` to go to `http://yoursite/?wc-api=WC_Gateway_Paypal`, not sure what those variables are for.  I have done this and guests are able to purchase just fine...  Also, you can bypass IPN altogether with your `Identity Token` from paypal, which you can put into WooCommerce->Settings->Pay Pal

Answer (score 1):

it is true that if you add those parameters to the SetEC API call it will enable guest checkout and present the credit card form on the hosted page. To add these parameters, however, you have to alter the source code of the plugin. If you are using Angelleye's plugin there is a setting:

PayPal Account Optional – If your PayPal account is setup with PayPal Account Optional enabled (available in your PayPal account profile) then setting this option here will provide a better checkout flow for non-PayPal users. It will be more obvious that you do not need a PayPal account in order to complete payment, and this will typically increase conversion rates.

you can see complete documentation [here](http://www.angelleye.com/paypal-express-checkout-for-woocommerce-setup-guide/).